# Python - use of globals() vs. code readability

Tags: python, design-patterns, state-machine

I'm working on a solid implementation of the *state design pattern* in python. In doing so I've found two ways of doing things.

Way 1

```
class State(object):
    transitions = [(None, None, None)]
    def __init__(self, state_context):
        self._context = state_context
        self.set_transitions()

    def set_transitions(self):
        """subclass may override this if access to self is
        needed in transitions"""
        pass

    def __call__(self, inp):
        new_state = self
        state_action_list = [(state, action) for cls, state,
                     action in self.transitions if
                     isinstance(inp, cls)]
        if 1 == len(state_action_list):
            state, action = state_action_list[0]
            if action is not None:
                action(inp)
            new_state = globals()[state](self._context)
        elif 1 < len(state_action_list):
            raise AmbiguousTransitionError(inp, self)    
        return new_state
```

Allows this usage:

```
class StateA(State):
    transitions = [(MsgA, "StateB", None)]

class StateB(State):
    def set_transitions(self):
        self.transitions = [(MsgB, "StateC", self._print_msg)]

    @staticmethod
    def _print_msg(inp):
        print "Inp: ", inp

class StateC(State):
    def set_transitions(self):
        self.transitions = [(MsgB, "StateB", None),
                    (MsgC, "StateA", self._print_context)]

    def _print_context(self, unused_inp):
        """example"""
        print "Context: ", self._context
```

And here's the change for Way 2

```
    def __call__(self, inp):
        [...]
        if action is not None:
            try:
                action(inp)
            except TypeError:
                action(self, inp)
            new_state = state(self._context)
        [...]
```

With the usage:

```
class StateA(State): pass
class StateB(State):
    @staticmethod
    def _print_msg(inp):
        print "Inp: ", inp

class StateC(State):
    def _print_context(self, unused_inp):
        """example"""
        print "Context: ", self._context

StateA.transitions = [(MsgA, StateB, None)]
StateB.transitions = [(MsgB, StateC, StateB._print_msg)]
StateC.transitions = [(MsgB, StateB, None),
              (MsgC, StateA, StateC._print_context)]
```

My issues with way No 1 are:

- typo in State name will fail at runtime / same typo in way 2 would not even start
- I have to use `globals()` to get to the Class, this by itself brings all sorts of trouble
- I need the `set_transitions` workaround to use methods as actions

However my concerns with option no. 2 are:

- it separates the states from their transitions and with a complex statemachine, this is going to be really messy
- I need the `except TypeError:` block to allow static methods to be used as actions

Now the question is, which way is the preferable one? Readability is probably better with No1?

Maybe there is also another third option I'm not seeing just now?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

/martin

BTW here's an example usage independent of the two options:

```
class Context(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._state = StateA(self)

    def handle(self, msg):
        self._state = self._state(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CONTEXT = Context()
    CONTEXT.handle(MsgA())
    CONTEXT.handle(MsgB())
    CONTEXT.handle(MsgC())
    CONTEXT.handle(MsgB())
```

Comment: Would this be a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: SethMMorton, good question. I don't know. I thought the specific question regarding `globals()` is a better fit for stackoverflow...

Comment: Could zour question be formulated like this: "How can I create my state transitions so that they can be verified while still maintaining readability?"?